# Scandinavian letters and special characters as in Word VBA Macro Shortcuts

Tags: vba, ms-word, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am trying to use Scandinavian letters as part of hotkeys in VBA as they always unassigned by default.

There is a list of [`wdKey`s in the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdkey), but they are missing all the Scandinavian and special characters.

Is there any way I could use Scandinavian letters or special characters in VBA as `wdKey`s? If I try to use `wdKeyÅ` it results in error. One can, however, use the Scandinavian letters as shortcuts via the drop down menus *so there should be a way to do that with code*.

For context, here is a block of code that does work, I would just like to change the `wdKeyL` to `wdKeyÅ` or equivalent. The `selecthighlight` macro selects the current paragraph and highlights it green. The `selecthighlightSC` assigns <kbd>ALT + L</kbd> shortcut to the former Macro.

```vb
Sub selecthighlight()
    Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
End Sub

Sub selecthighlight_SC()
    ' where to do customization
    CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate

    ' Add keybinding to this Shorcut
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKeyL), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
        Command:="selecthighlight"
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

P.S. This question [at another forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f66f9d6b-9b0f-45bc-90ca-3123f8d8f43c/scandinavian-letters-and-special-characters-in-wdkey-emenumerations?forum=isvvba) was not answered after three years, and since it was archived and cannot be removed, I decided to repost it here.

Comment: Look at what English letter is printed on your key. Use that.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: How to look at your keyboard? Lower your head in a nod-like motion, and move the eyeballs slightly in the same direction.

Comment: In case you want to understand the background, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790396/11683. The key binding works in terms of *virtual keys*, not *scan codes* or *characters*. Hence the `wdKey` enumeration. When you assign a shortcut for a menu, the UI likely still captures it in terms of *virtual keys*, but displays it in *characters* for your convenience, by [mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-toascii) the virtual key to a character.

Comment: It seems to work inconsistently with Keyboard layouts other than English. I confirmed with [autohotkey](https://jacks-autohotkey-blog.com/2016/04/14/understanding-autohotkey-keyboard-scan-codes-and-virtual-key-codes-beginning-hotkeys-part-12/) that the virtual codes were equivalent with both keyboard layouts , but the shortcuts only work with the English keyboard layout. Any idea how to go about this?