# How can I monitor for keys that were pressed with SHIFT Win32 LowLevelKeyboardProc

Tags: c, winapi

I have a program that logs all key presses. Currently, I'm using [ToUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicode) to convert virtual-key codes to their respective character equivalents.

The only issue I encounter is the fact that these characters do not show their correct values such as "!" or "$" when pressed with Shift + 1 and Shift + 4, respectively.

My current code is as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static BOOL isUppercase = FALSE;
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        BYTE buf[256];
        GetKeyboardState(buf);
        WCHAR charBuf[5];
        int key = ToUnicode(p->vkCode, p->scanCode, buf, charBuf, sizeof(charBuf), 2);
        printf("[%s]", charBuf);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can use some switch statements to check if the virual-key matches that of shift and print a keys respective value once a shift is pressed, however I want to avoid that.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: *"Where am I going wrong here?"* - You're calling `GetKeyboardState()` under a global context. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate) explains: *"The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads."*

Comment: OTOH [GetKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) does, although you must make a request for a specific key.

Comment: No. `GetKeyState()` follows the same rules as `GetKeyboardState()`: It returns the *synchronous* per-thread (or input-attached thread group) state.

Comment: *The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue*. I use this function, in the keyboard hook, for exactly this.

Comment: *"A thread"* here is the thread that **ultimately** receives the input in case none of the low-level input hooks reject it. The thread running the hook won't have its input state updated (and if it did it would happen only *after* its hook procedure has run).

Comment: That's why there's a distinction between WH_KEYBOARD and WH_KEYBOARD_LL.  The former runs inside the process that received the keystroke, so doesn't have trouble retrieving the keyboard state.  Disadvantage is that it requires the hook to live in a DLL that can be injected.

Comment: You need to set keyboard state `lpKeyState` for `ToUnicode`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783003 and [the code snippet](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/a47da3d4551b74bb8cc1f4c7447445ac594afb44/Samples/IME/cpp/SampleIME/KeyEventSink.cpp#L203 "Hello").

Answer (score 0):

`ToUnicode` has the function. As I said in comment, you need to set keyboard state `lpKeyState` for `ToUnicode`.

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783003, [the code snippet](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/a47da3d4551b74bb8cc1f4c7447445ac594afb44/Samples/IME/cpp/SampleIME/KeyEventSink.cpp#L203).

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    UINT code = 0x31;// 1 Key
    {
        //
        // Map virtual key to scan code
        //
        UINT scanCode = 0;
        scanCode = MapVirtualKey(code, 0);

        //
        // Keyboard state
        //
        BYTE abKbdState[256] = {};
        if (!GetKeyboardState(abKbdState))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        abKbdState[VK_SHIFT] = 0x80;

        //
        // Map virtual key to character code
        //
        WCHAR wch[10] = {};
        if (ToUnicode(code, scanCode, abKbdState, wch, 10, 0) == 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Shift 1]